# Database.Migrate() creating database but not tables, EF & .NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, database-migration, ef-core-2.0

This question has been asked a couple times but none of the solutions/documentation is working for me.

Scenario - I need to build a database from scratch and edit it with migrations all from code, according to the documentation the line below should create the database from the DbContext/ModelBuilder.

```
_dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

however this is only creating the database itself and none of the tables. If I run the below instead,

```
_dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

the database AND all the tables are created however this is not an option as I need to edit with migrations further down the line. I've tried the code below directly after the Migrate line but pendingMigrations is always 0.

```
var pendingMigrations = _dbContext.Database.GetAppliedMigrations().ToList();
        if (pendingMigrations.Any())
        {
            var migrator = _dbContext.Database.GetService<IMigrator>();
            foreach (var targetMigration in pendingMigrations)
                migrator.Migrate(targetMigration);
        }
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Shouldn't Database.Migrate() be creating the tables as well as the database?

Note - in testing I am deleting the database before trying another approach.

Comment: `_dbContext.Database.Migrate();` should create the tables. And it does it in my (and not only I guess) tests.

Comment: Found the answer, posting it now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another classic case of struggling with something for a day or two only to find the answer half an hour after posting a question here. Posting my solution incase other people have had a similar issue.

TLDR - `_dbContext.Database.Migrate();` doesn't create migrations.

Basically, `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` doesn't care about migrations, which is why it generated the full database inc tables (however then of course you can't migrate).

`_dbContext.Database.Migrate();` applies the migrations and creates the database if it doesn't exist however it doesn't create the tables if there's no migration.

Basically I have a project as a resource, I was trying to duplicate the project from a new application generated by the user but as I'd never run any migrations in the resource project there was nothing to migrate. Running the `Add-Migration Initial` in the PMC in the resource project gave the project it's initial migration files so then when I ran migrate on a new database it knew which tables to create.

Comment: +1. It's unfathomable to me how this isn't covered by the official documentation. And boy, the logic behind it! To create a new db you create a migration and migrate. /rant

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had multiple projects and `DesignTimeDbContextFactory` was pointing to a 
`MigrationsAssembly` but in startup `sqlOptions` were not.

[image]
[image]

so when DI creates `DbContext` it does't know there are pending migrations.

you can check you pending migrations with
`dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations();` before `Migrate();` to check if it has found migrations or not

Solution is add migration `MigrationsAssembly` in `sqlOptions`

```
 services.AddDbContext<BM_OCR_DbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServer => sqlServer.MigrationsAssembly("BM.OCR.Server"));
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful mixing EntityFramework and EntityFramework**Core**.

In my case i created the migration with:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration
```

Because '-Force' does not exist in EntityFrameworkCore i had to

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Remove-Migration
```

After this i could create the migration again and had the Methods 'Up' and 'Down' filled again. Nothing else worked.

Answer (score -1):

Another way - create an extension method in the EF Migration project. It will work without sqlServer.MigrationsAssembly() method.

```
namespace Project.Data;
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void AddEntityFramework(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var cnn = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(cnn));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs just use it

```
services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration);
```